# Complex integration, showing that arc integral vanishes

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I stumbled upon the following integral in QFT:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{k e^{ikr}}{k^2+m^2} dk$$

If We turn this into complex variable integral along semi-circle arc in the upper complex plane:

$$\oint \frac{z e^{izr}}{z^2+m^2} dz = 2\pi i Res(im) = \int_{arc} + \int_{\mathbb{R}}$$

where $\int_{\mathbb{R}}$ is what we need.

Residue could easily be evaluated, however I'm failing  to show that the $arc$ part vanishes in limit of infinite circle radius.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $z = R e^{i t}$.  Then show that the integral over the arc has a magnitude bounded by

$$\frac{R^2}{R^2-m^2} \int_0^{\pi} dt \, e^{-r R \sin{t}} $$

Finally, use the inequality $\sin{t} \ge \frac{2}{\pi} t$ for $t \in [0,\pi/2]$.  The result will be an easily doable integral and that the magnitude of the arc integral is bounded by $\pi/(r R)$ as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: I got up to your integral, but I don't see how $sint<\frac{2}{\pi}t$ works. This inequality implies $e^{-sint} > e^{-2t/\pi}$ and could not be used to upper bound integral.

Comment: @user3747890: sorry, I got the relation backward and didn't provide a range.  My deepest apologies.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the answer!

Comment: My question is, how you can say that for $t \in [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ the integral is bounded? I use the function \frac{-2}{\pi}t + 2 to bound it, but later I just obtain $e^R$ which is unbounded. I can not prove that the other part of the integral goes to 0.

Comment: @RichardClare: $\sin{(\pi-t)} = \sin{t}$.

Comment: @RichardClare: $$\sin{(\pi-t)} = \sin{\pi} \cos{t} - \cos{\pi} \sin{t} $$

Comment: sorry I was confusing what you said with $\sin(t - \pi)$. Of course by the sum of angles sine.

Comment: @RonGordon Thank you a lot. This solves a huge problem for me.